# Trace.WriteLine in ASP.NET Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, trace

when I use

```
Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("message", "Information");
```

in my azure-asp.net this does not show up in my  azure compute emulator, 
but if I do the same from my worker-role it works, any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is with SDK 1.3, right?  In 1.3, web roles by default run with full IIS, which means your actual web app code is in a different app domain from your RoleEntryPoint.  I believe the compute emulator only shows messages from RoleEntryPoint (WebRole.cs or WorkerRole.cs).

To double check, try putting a trace message in OnStart in WebRole.cs; I'm guessing it will show up.

Comment: this is also true for SDK 2.0, as you'd expect

Answer (score 2):

Add a TraceListener of the type :

```
Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime.DevelopmentFabricTraceListener,
    Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime, 
    Version=1.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

The reason is due to not having this TraceListener in the AppDomain of the ASP.NET application - which is different to where WebRole.cs runs. All changed in v1.3 with the introduction of full IIS.

http://blog.bareweb.eu/2011/01/tracing-to-azure-compute-emulator-sdk-v1-3/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Trace.TraceInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64tdffaz.aspx) instead:

> Writes an informational message to the trace listeners in the Listeners collection using the specified message.