# Is tracing allowed within a asp .net web role?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

I am trying to develop a asp.net web role that allows to tracing when, for instance, clicking a button. I have tried lots of things, namely I have also tried what i suggested in the question "[Trace.WriteLine in ASP.NET Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4496027/199220)", but it does not work with me. Moreover, when doing what is suggested as an answer to that question it appears to me an error message:

> Line 10:         add type="Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime.DevelopmentFabricTraceListener, Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The **DevelopmentFabricTraceListener** you're adding here is only available when running in the emulator. You cannot use this when:

- Deploying to Windows Azure (staging/production)
- Directly starting the web project (instead of starting the cloud project)

How are you starting your PHP web application?

Comment: I would like that, when putting in the Application_Start of Global.asax the information Trace.WriteLine("Hello Cloud"),that it appeared in Compute Emulator. But it doesn't appear at all.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to enable tracing at the site level and browse the trace.axd file.  If you use Trace.Warn, it will show up in the report there in red which makes it easier to see.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c.aspx

For the trace listener, you should be using:

```
type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
```

That one will work in Azure.

Take a look at:

http://www.azuresupport.com/2010/03/getting-started-with-windows-azure-diagnostics-and-monitoring/

Comment: Hi, thank very much for your answer. Still, when I put in the Application_Start of Global.asax and on click button event of Default.aspx the information Trace.WriteLine("Hello Cloud"), it does not appear in Compute Emulator. Is there any reason for this?